# Create Test Class for the simple Trigger

Tags: unit-test, after-trigger

I'm writing a simple trigger for Contacts.
But my coverage is 19%. Can anyone help me figure it out?

My Trigger:

```
trigger ConCase on Contact (after insert) {
    List<Case> CaseList = new List<Case>();

    for(Contact Ct : trigger.new){
        if(Ct.Level__c == 'Primary'  ){
            CaseList.add(
                new Case(
                    AccountId = Ct.AccountId,
                    ContactId = Ct.Id,
                    Priority = 'High'
                )
            );
        } 
    if(!CaseList.isEmpty())
        insert Case;

}
```

My Test method

```
 @isTest static void CreateCase() { 
 Contact con = new Contact(LastName='TestCase', Level__c = 'Primary');     
  Test.startTest();
  insert con ;
  Test.stopTest();   
  Contact cn = [SELECT ID, LastName, Level__c FROM Contact WHERE ID=:con.Id];
  System.assertEquals('TestCase',con.LastName);
```

}

Comment: Your trigger is running when new contact being insert. But the test class doesn't insert any Contact, You should insert some to in order to get coverage. + should insert contacts with different Level__c per the if statement in your trigger logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is on `Contact` object and the test code which you have posted is inserting `Case` records. If you just run this test method, the test coverage will be 0% not even 19%.

You should insert some `Contact` records from your test method and try to use a mix of records with different values (Primary, Secondary, Tertiary) for `Level__c` field. Try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

Also, you need to fix the `System.assert` statement as well.

**Edit:** Instead of inserting just single contact, you can insert multiple contact records

Change following line

```
Contact con = new Contact(LastName='TestCase', Level__c = 'Primary');
```

to

```
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
for(Integer i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    // inserts 3 records each with different value for Level__c
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName='TestCase ' + i);
    con.Level__c = ((Math.mod(i, 3) == 1) ? 'Primary' : (Math.mod(i, 3) == 2 ? 'Secondary' : 'Tertiary'));
    contacts.add(con);
}
insert contacts;
```